# Chart series data point click through Kinect V2

Tags: wpf, kinect

I am developing a WPF application which is to be operated through Kinect. I am using Kinect for Windows V2.0. (I have referred Controls Basics code given in Kinect Code samples V2)

In my WPF application, I am having a Line series Chart control. `System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting`

I want to click a series point through Kinect Hand gesture.
How I can do that? I tried with normal Hand pointer click gesture. But it doesn't work.

**edit**

I expect a data point to be clickable. Means I have handled SelectedChanged event of the line chart. Set IsSelectable = true. So I am able to get respective data point details when I click the point through mouse. I want same to happen through Kinect. Below is the code for Line chart.

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> valueList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
valueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Developer", 60));
valueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Misc", 20));
valueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Tester", 50));
valueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("QA", 30));
valueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Project Manager", 40));
lineChart.DataContext = valueList;
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code you tried so far.

Comment: Hi, I just added standard code for any Line series chart. Nothing specific to Kinect.
List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> valueList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
            valueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Developer", 60));
            valueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Misc", 20));
            valueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Tester", 50));
            valueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("QA", 30));
            valueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Project Manager", 40));

            lineChart.DataContext = valueList;

Answer (score 0):

I just added standard code for any Line series chart. I expect a data point to be clickable. Means I have handled `SelectedChanged` event of the line chart. `Set IsSelectable = true`. So I am able to get respective data point details when I click the point through mouse.
I want same to happen through Kinect.
Below is the code for Line chart.

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> valueList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
valueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Developer", 60));
valueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Misc", 20));
valueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Tester", 50));
valueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("QA", 30));
valueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Project Manager", 40));
lineChart.DataContext = valueList;
```

Comment: Please add those details to your original question by editing as this only provides details to the question - not an answer.

Comment: Yes, I know. I am sorry for the confusion as I just started posting a question in this forum.

Comment: No problem at all - that`s why I told you ;-) I added the code to your question. Maybe you can delete this "answer" and the comment you added to your original question.